# postfix header_checks pcre (lookahead)

Tags: pcre, postfix-mta, regex-lookarounds

Currently a lot of spam mails containing links to trojans go around. This mails are relativ good fakes, they mostly look like legitimate delivery announcements from delivery services like UPS or DHL.

But there is one significant difference: Legitimate mails, e. g. from DHL have a from like `From: "DHL name"<name@dhl.com>`
The trojans from is like `"DHL name"<name@any_domain.tld>`

So I want to block any mail, which starts with `From: "DHL`, but has any other domain but dhl after the @.

I think, that the following lookahead should fit: `/^From: "dhl(?!.*@dhl)/ REJECT No trojans please`

Don't work.

Afaik the regexes in header_checks are not case-senitive. To avoid any confusion with special characters like " and @, I tried the more simple form `From: .dhl(?!.*dhl)`

Don't work either.

Is there something wrong with my regex, or with my understanding of pcre's in postfix?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! The problem was my own fault. In `main.cf`, `header_checks` was bound in as `regexp:` rather than `pcre:` so it did not support the enhanced syntax of PCRE.